# linearly independent solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, reference-request, homogeneous-equation

From [Calculus by Stewart](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-2ndOrderLinearEqns_Stu.pdf) (RIP):

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. If we consider the case of Theorem 4 for Equation (2) with P, Q and R being constant, is such case proven with what comes later in the chapter namely:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

?

If not, why?

2. Where can I find a proof for Theorem 4?

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes; in each case, you've found two linearly independent solutions to the original equation. As for (2), what have you tried?

Comment: @CarlHeckman For 1, thanks! ^-^ For 2, nvm. Edited to reference request :P

Comment: For the proof of Theorem 4: there are 2 key-points: (a) two maximal solutions $y_1,\ y_2$ are linearly independent if and only if for all $t$ in the domain the vectors $(y_1(t),y'_1(t)),\ (y_2(t), y'_2(t))$ are independent (if a linear combination of those is $0$ at some point, then it solves a certain Cauchy problem...). (b) If you have $(y_1(0),y'_1(0)),\ (y_2(0),y'_2(0))$ independent, then you can realise all initial conditions via a linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks! ^-^ Seems advanced. Is it a theorem the can be proved in an elem ODE class? Do you have a reference? I actually discovered this in a long exam for an undergrad elem ODE class. Apparently such fact was proven in their class and then it was to be used to prove something else. I have a feeling it was really Theorem 4 and not just the case of constant coefficients. At such point in the class, I believe, the students are not expected to have knowledge of elem linear algebra or elem real analysis, although elem linear algebra is used later on in the class.

Comment: See below. It's a neat application of the Wronskian.

Comment: @BCLC It takes some passages, but it is most certainly undergraduate ODE (personally, I saw it on my second year at university). I studied on lecture notes, so I lack a precise English reference, but it think this is covered in any introductory book to ODE. The only important result it really uses is the existence and uniqueness theorem (Cauchy-Lipschitz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), you can use the Wronskian. Suppose that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are as given, and let $y_3$ be a solution to the differential equation
$$Py'' + Qy' + Ry = 0.$$
Let $A=\left[\matrix{y_1&y_1'&y_1''\cr y_2&y_2'&y_2''\cr y_3&y_3'&y_3''}\right]$ (the transpose of the Wronskian matrix) and $\vec v = \left[\matrix{R\cr Q\cr P\cr}\right]$. Then 
$$A\vec v = \left[\matrix{Ry_1+Qy_1'+Py_1''\cr Ry_2+Qy_2'+Py_2''\cr Ry_3+Qy_3'+Py_3''\cr }\right]=\left[\matrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr}\right],$$
because $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$ are all solutions.

Since $P\not=0$, that means there is a nonzero vector $\vec v$ such that $A\vec v=\vec0$; this means $A$ cannot be invertible. Hence, $\det A=0$, which means the set $\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ is linearly dependent.

Now, to finish it off: There are real numbers $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that
$$c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2 + c_3 y_3 = 0.$$
We cannot have $c_3=0$, because then $\{y_1,y_2\}$ would be linearly dependent ($c_1$ or $c_2$ would have to be nonzero); hence
$$y_3 = {-c_1 \over c_3}\cdot y_1 + {-c_2 \over c_3}\cdot y_2,$$
proving the theorem.

Also (and easier to prove), any linear combination is also a solution.

Comment: Thanks Carl Heckman. I think anyone who's taken linear algebra can understand it, but not all ODE classes require linear algebra to a similar extent, I believe. Did you learn this in an elem ODE class? PS I'm not sure I understand, but it seems to make sense so I upvoted. If there are other upvotes or no problems, I guess I'll accept answer.

Comment: The Wronskian is taught in Differential Equation classes. Linear Algebra should be taken before Differential Equations; it introduces concepts like subspaces, linear combinations, linear independence, etc., which are useful in D.E. ... And I actually saw this proof (or something similar) when I was a graduate student; I was observing another student teaching a class.